Microsoft Graph Api Permissions - list of all applications
I'm looking for a resource graph get url that brings all the resource graph api permissions for all app registrations, does anyone know if it would be possible?
With this request, I would monitor the graph's most sensitive permissions, such as writing, with logic apps.


like this: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$select=id,appId,displayName,appRoles,oauth2PermissionScopes,resourceSpecificApplicationPermissions

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can you GET /servicePrincipals api
Documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0
Example from Microsoft graph explorer - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=servicePrincipals&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com


I would like to know if it is possible to monitor, through logs or some logic apps, the change in permissions of an api from an api permissions. Example: When someone adds Application.Read.All
for Microsoft.Graph I wanted to see these logs, to monitor
